# DataContract Serializer doesnt de-serialize List

Tags: c#, wcf, datacontractserializer

I am tryng to deserialize the following XML into a class using the datacontract serializer.

```
"<ns2:MemberCarePlanModel xmlns:ns2=\"http://v3.ua.test.com\">
 <ns2:memberGoal><ns2:goalDescription>Has received diabetes self-management overview</ns2:goalDescription>
 <ns2:memberId>111111111</ns2:memberId>
 <ns2:goalId>be406994-47a6-4802-8dd6-9616bfbaaead</ns2:goalId>
 </ns2:memberGoal>
 </ns2:MemberCarePlanModel>"
```

My code for the DataContract classes is

```
  namespace Medventive.Registry.Service.ServiceImplementation.VITALServices
  {
[DataContract(Namespace = @"http://v3.ua.test.com")]
[KnownType(typeof(MemberCareProblemModel))]
[KnownType(typeof(MemberGoalActivityModel))]
public class MemberGoalModel 
{
    /*
     * <xs:sequence>
    <xs:element maxOccurs="unbounded" minOccurs="0" name="careProblem" nillable="true" type="tns:MemberCareProblemModel"/>
    <xs:element maxOccurs="unbounded" minOccurs="0" name="goalActivity" nillable="true" type="tns:MemberGoalActivityModel"/>
    <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="goalDescription" type="xs:string"/>
    <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="memberId" type="xs:string"/>
    <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="goalId" type="xs:string"/>
    </xs:sequence>
     */

    //[DataMember(EmitDefaultValue = false, Name = "careProblem", Order = 1)]
    //public List<MemberCareProblemModel> careProblem { get; set; }

    //[DataMember(EmitDefaultValue = false, Name = "goalActivity", Order = 2)]
    //public List<MemberGoalActivityModel> goalActivity { get; set; }

     [DataMember(EmitDefaultValue = false, Name = "goalDescription", Order = 1)]
     public string goalDescription { get; set; }

     [DataMember(EmitDefaultValue = false, Name = "memberId", Order = 2)]
     public string memberId { get; set; }

     [DataMember(EmitDefaultValue = false, Name = "goalId", Order = 3)]
     public string goalId { get; set; }
    }
 }


namespace Medventive.Registry.Service.ServiceImplementation.VITALServices
{
[DataContract(Namespace = @"http://v3.ua.test.com", Name="MemberCarePlanModel")]
[KnownType(typeof(MemberGoalModel))]
public class MemberCarePlanModel
{

    [DataMember(EmitDefaultValue = false, Name = "memberGoal", Order = 1)]
    public List<MemberGoalModel> memberGoal { get; set; }
}
}
```

I cant figure out the problem here as to why this code doesnt de-serialize the list or member goals. If works fine if there is a single class of memberGoal inside the carePlan class, but fails for the list.

Below is my deserialization code. I convert the xml to a memory stream and pass it to my deserializer.

```
     protected static T Deserialize<T>(Stream stream)
    {
        DataContractSerializer ser = new DataContractSerializer(typeof(T));
        XmlReaderSettings rs = new XmlReaderSettings
        {
            ConformanceLevel = ConformanceLevel.Fragment,
        };
        XmlReader r = XmlReader.Create(stream, rs);
        while (!r.EOF)
        {
            T obj = (T)ser.ReadObject(r);
            return obj;
        }

        return default(T);

    }
```

Comment: try to generate example class and serialize it to xml, that way you'll find where you got it wrong

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apprently DataContract Serializer does not serialize list objects.

I fixed the above problem with the following code

```
var memberGoals = from v in doc.Root.Descendants(Common.Constants.NameSpace + "memberGoal")
                              select new MemberGoalModel
                              {
                                  goalDescription = v.Element(Common.Constants.NameSpace + "goalDescription").Value,
//Assign Other Properties here. 

                              };
            //return Deserialize<MemberCarePlanModel>(ms);
            return memberGoals.ToList()
```